# Java Web Services in Wildfly/JBoss & IntelliJ setup

Tags: web-services, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee, wildfly, jax-ws

I have spent five days trying to get a simple HelloWorld web service to work in IntelliJ and this is my last chance to get it to work.
I am still very much a beginner in Web Services especially with Java, so please bare with me.

I have raised several tickets with JetBrains complaining about the outdated and vague documentation, the guys have been very helpful but have acknowledged there is a limitation, that it's not as straight forward to setup & the documentation is in fact outdated.
I am not getting a proper clean solution.

I was wondering if anyone uses the latest version of IntelliJ to build web services?

I am using Wildly, JBoss as the application server

I asked if I should be creating a Web App or a Rest Service as there is no user interaction since it will be a pure Web Service.
I have been advised to use a Rest Service, But I have created it both ways & attached the screenshots where applicable.

1. As a REST Service:

A simple project with one Web Service and a Web Method which returns a simple string:

1. Create a new project, choose Web App or Rest Service?
   [image]
2. Choose XML Web Services? With CXF Implementation?
   This is where I am a bit confused.

According to this link: https://developer.jboss.org/message/799428#799428
JBoss comes with its own implementation of Web Services JBossWS & It is recommended to use that instead of external Apache CXF?
So I'm not sure if I need to do anything, in this case it should work out of the box,
but it simply does not as I am getting exceptions:

[image]

This is the simple Project structure:
I have a basic web service class with the @WebService annotation:

```
package com.testwebservices.MyFirstWebService;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class MyFirstWebService {

    public String firstWebMethod(){
        return "Mama is the best!";
    }

}
```

Now I am trying to expose this as a web service but its just not happening:

[image]

Now I am getting these options, If I choose anything other than the default Apache Axis I get a path incorrect issue,
See screenshot below with Default Apache Axis:
[image]

And when I choose CXF:
[image]

If JBossWS provides support for this out of the box, should it not work easily? Especially as most IDE's make this easy out of the box.

When I run the project nothing happens, there is no WSDL file, I went to the admin console, no mention of it. The documentation is vague.

2. As a Web App

When I choose the web app option and follow the same steps as above.

I get this exception:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet

What is the best way to setup a Web Services project in intelliJ?
I have no clue how to configure this or set it up.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I might encourage you to turn it around - use IntelliJ to build but get the general structure right first.  Start with the Java code:

HeartBeatService.java

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public class HeartBeatService {

    @WebMethod
    public HeartbeatResponse getHeartBeat() {
        return new HeartbeatResponse("OK");
    }
}
```

HeartbeatResponse.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class HeartbeatResponse {
    private String status;

    public HeartbeatResponse() {
    }

    public HeartbeatResponse(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

a `pom.xml` using the most recent things I could find:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.hotjoe.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-super-simple</artifactId>
    <name>JAX-WS Integration Example</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and, lastly, a `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.0">
</web-app>
```

Put this into a maven structure **and make sure it compiles with `mvn clean package`** and *then* import that into IntelliJ.

This code is derived from my repository at https://github.com/stdunbar/jaxws-sample if you need more details.

Comment: I downloaded Eclipse yesterday & found it to be very clunky, IntelliJ is much better, but the guys there have told me the support for Web Services isn't great, they don't have very good Apache CXF Integration, Im not too sure about this, I will give it one last change, if not I will attempt this. Is there a way to create web services with a maven archetype?

Comment: There is no reason in a modern Wildfly to ever directly interact with CXF.  Use the standards and let the container (Wildfly) take care of the implementation details.

Comment: Im sorry, this might sound like a silly question, forgive me Im still not very good at this, when you mean build it first then import it in IntelliJ, Do you mean build it in a text editor somewhere else? Or just create these classes and then compile the project with mvm clean? Do I just create a basic web app first?  Where will I see the WSDL file?

Comment: If you use my example from github, the WSDL is automatically generated at `http://localhost:8080/sample/ProductService?wsdl`.  You don't have to do anything to generate that WSDL.

Comment: great, working on it, I just wanted to see the general pattern, so eventually when I build my own I am able to understand it, I am just learning maven thoroughly tonight, then I can try this